# Finding optimal order of all nodes to be visited in a graph

Tags: graph, tree, routes

The following problem comes from geography, but I don't kown of any GIS method to solve it. I think it's solution can be found with graph analysis, but I need some guidance to think in the right direction.

There is a geographical area, say a state. It is subdivided in several quadrants, which are subdivided further, and once again. So its a tree structure with the state as root, and 3 levels of child nodes, each parent having 4 childs. But from the perspective of the underlying process its more like a completed graph, since in theory a node is directly reachable from each other node.

The subdivisions reflect map sheet boundaries at different mapscales. Each mapsheet has to reviewed by a topographer in a time span dependend on the complexity of the map contents.

While reviewing the map, the underlying digital data is locked in the database. And as the objects have topological relationships with objects of neighboring map sheet (eg. roads crossing the map boundaries), all 8 surrounding map sheets are locked also.

The question is, what is the optimal order in which the leafs (on the lowest level) should be visited to satisfy following requirements:

- each node has to be visited
- we do not deal with travel times but with the timespan a worker spent at each node (map)
- the time spent at a node is different
- while the worker is at a node, all adjacent nodes cannot be visited; this is true also for other workers too; they cannot work on a map side by side with a map already being processed
- if a node has been visited, other nodes having the same parent should be prefered as next node; this is true for all levels of parents

Finally for a given number of nodes/maps and workers we need an ordered series of nodes, each worker visites to minimize the overall time, and the time for each parent also.

After designing the solution the real work begins. We will recognize, that the actual work may need more or less time, than expected. Therefore it is necessary to replay the solution up to a current state, and design a new solution with slightly different conditions, leading to another order of nodes.

Has somebody an idea which data structure and which algorithm to use to find a solution for such kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not havig a ready made algorithm, but may be the following helps devising one:

Your exakt topologie is not cler. I assume from the other remarks,
you are targeting a regular structure. In your case a 4x4 square.

Given the restriction that working on a node blocks any adjacient node can be used to identify a starting condition for the algorithm:

Put a worker to one corner of the total are and then put others 
at ditance 2 from this (first in x direction and as soon as the side is "filled" with y direction . This will occupy all (x,y) nodes (x,y in 0,2,..,2n where 2n <= size of grid)

With a 4x4 area this will allow a maximum of 4 workers, and will position a worker per child node of each 2 level grid node)

from this let each worker process (x,y),(x+1),(y+1),(x+1,y). This are the 4 nodes of a small square.

If a worker is done but can not proceed to the next planned node, you may advance it to the next free node from the schedule.

The more workers you will have, the higher the risk for contention will be. If you have any estimates on the expected wokload per node,
then you may prefer starting with the most expensive ones and arrange the processing sequence to continue with the ones that have the highest total expected costs.